# EGREP and AWK equivalent command in Windows

Tags: windows, git, bash, awk, grep

I'm building an automated pre-commit script [based in the Carlos Buenos Vinos tutorial](https://carlosbuenosvinos.com/write-your-git-hooks-in-php-and-keep-them-under-git-control/), but the BIG problem is: I work in a company that use Windows in the dev computers (I know I know and I can't do nothing about this sry).

The script has the following method:

```
private function extractCommitedFiles()
{
    $output = array();
    $rc = 0;

    exec('git rev-parse --verify HEAD 2> /dev/null', $output, $rc);

    $against = '4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904';
    if ($rc == 0) {
        $against = 'HEAD';
    }

    // unix / linux
    // exec("git diff-index --cached --name-status $against | egrep '^(A|M)' | awk '{print $2;}'", $output);
    // windows
    exec("git diff-index --cached --name-status $against | egrep '^(A|M)' | awk '{print $2;}'", $output);

    return $output;
}
```

So... does anybody have an idea to an equivalent command to the line bellow?

```
exec("git diff-index --cached --name-status $against | egrep '^(A|M)' | awk '{print $2;}'", $output);
```

I must have the following result if I run this command in UNIX/Bash:

```
core/web/favicon.ico                        
core/web/htaccess.txt                       
core/web/index.html                         
core/web/slim.php                           
core/web/swagger/css/print.css              
core/web/swagger/css/reset.css              
core/web/swagger/css/screen.css             
core/web/swagger/css/style.css              
core/web/swagger/css/typography.css         
core/web/swagger/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf
```

But using exec('... without the egrep and awk commands I'm having the following results:

```
A       core/web/htaccess.txt                      
A       core/web/index.html                        
A       core/web/slim.php                          
A       core/web/swagger/css/print.css             
A       core/web/swagger/css/reset.css             
A       core/web/swagger/css/screen.css            
A       core/web/swagger/css/style.css             
A       core/web/swagger/css/typography.css        
A       core/web/swagger/fonts/DroidSans-Bold.ttf
```

Thank u guys!

Comment: I could. But I'm trying to automate the task because we have others developers and the idea is version the script that will do the job without any additional manual tasks. I get close with the command **git ls-files -m** but there is not option -a for added files :(

Comment: The egrep command only let those lines through that start with A or M.  The awk command just prints the "second column" which is the filename.  So you get the files added or modified.

Comment: It should not be hard to modify your own program to perform that part -- skip lines which don't start with `A` or `M`; skip the first field and the whitespace after it and reap the file name from the rest of the line.  (The Awk script would work incorrectly for any file names with whitespace in their names.)

Comment: It would help if your question indicated which language that script is written in.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that command is a bad example. It is hardly ever necessary to use `grep` and `awk` in the same pipeline, since `awk` is vastly more powerful. So, the command should be shortened to

```
 awk '/^(A|M)/ {print $2}'
```

Secondly, even that is a bad example, since `git diff-index` has various output options, including `--name-only` and `--diff-filter`, which can be combined as

```
git diff-index --cached --name-only --diff-filter=AM $against
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download windows versions of the tools and add the bin folder to the PATH variable.

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm

For "egrep" you can use "grep -E". "gawk" will do the job exactly like "awk" in your case.

Comment: I could. But I'm trying to automate the task because we have others developers and the idea is versioning the script that will do the job without any additional manual tasks.